# Python Selenium Firefox private browsing with cookies

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I need to add cookies via Webdriver using Firefox with Python. It works in normal mode, but not in `private` mode.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
capabities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabities.update({"javascriptEnabled":True})
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabities, firefox_profile=firefoxProfile)
driver.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
driver.add_cookie({"name":"drag", "value": "lol", "domain": "httpbin.org"})
driver.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
```

No matter how many times I refresh the driver, cookies don't load. There is nothing present in `document.cookie` in console log. It works fine in Chrome(not tested in incognito), and Firefox(non private).

I am aware in selenium private mode is redundant and I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425116/python-start-firefox-with-selenium-in-private-mode) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode).

But I cannot change much of the code. I need this feature to set cookie even in private mode in Firefox.

> Firefox 66.0.1
>
> Geckodriver 0.23.0 ( 2018-10-04)
>
> Python selenium 3.14.1

**Edit 1**

I have tested with chrome(incognito) and it seems working

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
capabities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabities.update({"javascriptEnabled":True})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabities, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
driver.add_cookie({"name":"drag", "value": "lol", "domain": "httpbin.org"})
driver.refresh()
driver.get_cookies()
```

> Chromium 73.0.3683.75 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04
>
> ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d)
>
> Python selenium 3.14.1

I could also find some issues with firefox in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342704/firefox-private-browsing-requires-2-page-loads-to-set-cookies) but couldn't quite make sense out of it. The version of firefox used there is also old so there might be some changes in the present version.

Comment: The whole point of private mode on firefox/incognito mode on chrome is that it doesn't use cookies. If you want to use cookies you need to use a normal browsing window

Comment: Would it be easier to do it the other way around? Open non-private Firefox in python Selenium, clear cache and erase cookies, then set cookies in the way that is already working for you? Is private mode a necessity for what you are trying to do, or can it be accomplished through other means?

Comment: @DavidDancey Iam did that back then as a work around.